# What are all the 3 nuances of 普通に?

Tags: reading-comprehension, definitions

As far I know, 普通に mean normally/ordinary in English. So I've seen it use a lot of times like this.

However, there are a lot of contexts which it seems like the speaker uses it to show surprise

One example I met recently

> 今日久しぶりに女とキスしたんだけど、普通に嫌だったんだよな

The character used to be a playboy but after settling into a relationship, he stopped seeing many girls. However, recently one of his exes kissed him and he confesses this to his current partner.  The 普通に here seem to be used similar to 意外に?

How are Jisho 2 and 3 definition used?

The definition

> 1. normally; ordinarily; usually; generally; commonly​Only applies to ふつうに, See also 普通
>    Adverb (fukushi)
> 2. by anyone's standards; by normal standards; sufficiently; actually; genuinely; truly​Colloquial, used when giving a positive assessment, esp. of something that exceeds expectations
>    Adverb (fukushi)
> 3. without any issues; without any difficulty; (surprisingly) well; just fine; naturally​Colloquial, describes an

Comment: Could you at least provide the text of the three definitions you've seen on Jisho?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different usage of 普通に?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63326/different-usage-of-%e6%99%ae%e9%80%9a%e3%81%ab) It doesn't mean 意外に.

Comment: Among those three, the second definition is the one used in your sentence. "It was just plain disgusting".

Answer (score 0):

Its usage in this context is meant to exemplify how "ordinary" it has become for him to feel this way. For example, say a person was an absolute beginner in something, but then practices and gets skilled at something. They can then perform things effortlessly (普通に). Similarly, here it shows how something used to be different, but now the new state has become the ordinary.

This is a bit different from the other meaning ("according to my standards"). For example you can say これ普通にくさい, and it doesn't imply anything about a standard changing. In this use, 普通に means "according to the ordinary (standard)". E.g. 普通に通れる would mean "by any ordinary standard it can pass", i.e. "there is definitely enough space".

I guess the two uses are similar in the sense that in both cases something is "ordinary" / "unremarkable" / "does not need special input to the situation".